# how can I split strings into continuous substrings e.g: string_inputs: IN PYTHON3

Tags: python, python-3.x

how can I split strings into continuous sub strings e.g:
**string_inputs:**

```
AAAATTTT ATATATAT
```

**output_needed:**

```
AA,AA,AA,AT,TT,TT,TT
```

Comment: A tip: think of Python slices and a for loop.

Comment: Check what slices you want - in your example that would be [0:2], [2:4], etc. Be aware that your can call rage(start, stop, step) to get 0, 2, etc. Use a loop to create slices of the string.

Comment: thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

```
string_inputs = "AAAATTTTATATATAT"

#Note the `len(string_inputs) - 1` in the range; do according to what you desire as your output
d_out = [string_inputs[i:i+2] for i in range(0, len(string_inputs) - 1)]

d_out = ['AA', 'AA', 'AA', 'AT', 'TT', 'TT', 'TT', 'TA', 'AT', 'TA', 'AT', 'TA', 'AT', 'TA', 'AT']
```

Answer (score 0):

You can obtain every two substrings with [`zip()`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/functions.html#zip) here:

```
>>> string = 'AAAATTTTATATATAT'
>>> ','.join(x + y for x, y in zip(string, string[1:]))
'AA,AA,AA,AT,TT,TT,TT,TA,AT,TA,AT,TA,AT,TA,AT'
```

This is also another way:

```
>>> ','.join(map(''.join, zip(string, string[1:])))
'AA,AA,AA,AT,TT,TT,TT,TA,AT,TA,AT,TA,AT,TA,AT'
```

Or even something like this:

```
>>> ','.join(map(lambda x, y: x + y, string, string[1:]))
'AA,AA,AA,AT,TT,TT,TT,TA,AT,TA,AT,TA,AT,TA,AT'
```

Answer (score 0):

This does what you're looking for.

```
string = "AAAATTTTATATATAT"
step = 2
split = [string[i:i+step] for i in range(0, len(string), step)]
print(",".join(split))
```

`step` is the chunk you want to split your string into. And the last line joins it with the `,` as in your example to give you the final output `AA,AA,TT,TT,AT,AT,AT,AT`